# Hostname not resolving to IP addresses for Linux computers in an AD Domain

Tags: dns, active-directory, realm

I am joining Linux and Windows instances to an AD domain (). The machines are joining fine to the domain and I can use ssh/RDP using the AD credentials to login to the machines post domain join.

I can also get all the computer objects (host names) by running `Get-ADComputer -Filter *` on a windows server and providing the domain credentials. The issue is that, the host names for Linux based computers are not resolving to an IP address. Whereas all Windows hosts are resolving fine.

`nslookup <windows-host>`  is returning host's FQDN and the IP address.

`nslookup <linux-host>`  is returning Non-existent domain.

**P.S: All these resources (windows and Linux hosts) are in the same network, using same DHCP/DNS server and can communicate to each other with no issues. Also I can resolve and connect to the AD domain from all these hosts**

Any idea why this could be happening and how to resolve this ?
My use case is to get the IPs of all the computer objects in my AD domain.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when using DHCP Windows will attempt to register its own A and possibly PTR records in the configured DNS, not sure about Linux. You may configure your DHCP server to update DNS for the clients (instead of leaving it to the clients themselves), i.e.:

> To configure a DHCP server to register and to update client information with its configured DNS servers, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the DHCP properties for the server
> 2. Click **DNS**, click **Properties**, click to select the **Enable DNS dynamic updates according to the settings below** check box, and then click **Always dynamically update DNS A and PTR records**.

*Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-dns-dynamic-updates-windows-server-2003*